# PendingIntent is triggered earlier than I intended

Tags: java, android

I have a problem developing an alarm clock in Android.
When I trigger `PendingIntent` containing an `Activity` which MUST be launched at the scheduled time, it works well.
However, when the alarm is ringing and I press snooze for 5 minutes and trigger the SAME `Activity` with different request code, it launches right after I press snooze.

Here is the part of my source code in `PushActivity`:

```
private void setAlarm() {
    final int FIVE_MINUTES = 1000 * 60 * 5;
    int replacedCode = alarmCode + 1;
    attempt = attempt+1;
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PushActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(PushActivity.this,
            replacedCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, FIVE_MINUTES,
    pendingIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The time value for `set()` with an alarm type of `ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP` needs to be specified based on `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()`. If you are looking to do something five minutes from now, use `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()+FIVE_MINUTES`, not just `FIVE_MINUTES`.